# Callback method after a new object is initialized but not after find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I have a `Secret` model that has attribute `token`. I need to generate this token after the object is initialized for the first time, i.e., after `Secret.new`, but not after `Secret.find`

I couldn't find any callback that fits my purpose. It seems that `after_initialize` excluding `after_find` would have work.

How should I deal with this situation? Am I doing something smelly that Rails wasn't prepared for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the after_initialize callback you could check to see if the record is new or not via `secret.new_record?`  Then, only generate your token for new records.